# Encrypt and decrypt

Tags: c#, javascript

I wrote Decrypt and Encrypt with C# and used it in my project, and right now it works But I am wondering that I have to write Decrypt and Encrypt with JavaScript for Sniff or it is enough?

Comment: Are Encrypt, Decrypt and Sniff certain products or libraries?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? to protect your website you can use HTTPS and SSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you clarify your issue.

You have a client application which communicates data back to the server.
Once data is received by the server, it is encrypted/decrypted using your methods.

But you're worried about the plain text version of that data being "sniffed" while it is in transit between your server & client.

If that's the case then you should look at getting a Secure Cert (SSL) for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not encrypt data at client side.

Its only as good as **plain-text** for anyone know a little bit of JavaScript.

Comment: Not strictly speaking true. You might want to encrypt something with a public key before sending it as part of a form submission to prevent plain text being sent over the wire.

Comment: Fairly sure that's what SSL is for ;)

Comment: If you use public / private key encryption you can send something encrypted on the client side from client to server securely. Yes, SSL can be used on websites to secure communication as well (if you don't take into account some of the problems with SSL).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot call C# .NET code from JavaScript. If you are using ASP.NET, you can call related .NET functions as part of the ASP web page.

Comment: Unless you can expose a service wrapping the C# method.

Comment: I know that I can't. I called my functions form C# but everybody tell me , i have to write some JavaScript code in Html page because of sniff...It is right?